# How to run Text Classification using SVMTool-1.3 or SkLearn?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, nltk, svm

I'm beginner in NLP. I want to use SVMTool kit to classify the English corpus Text, features are word starting with `@` and `#`.

How to classify English corpus text in sklearn svm,features are word starting with `@` and `#`.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#classification

Comment: Thank you.How to add our own text data in Svm Sklearn ?

Comment: You should probably reprocess data to get interesting words ie `@#` then use them!

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html